# keep content the same when changing resolution

Tags: html, css

I have some CSS added to my HTML document to center a list of awards I have in my HTML but when I change the resolution of the browser or my computer resolution it turns it into a mess. This is what I have so far for my CSS and HTML:

```css
.awards {
  margin-left:400px;
  margin-right:400px;
  background-color:grey;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:5px;
  border-color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "awards">
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Best Sailing Yacht Interior</li>
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Best Sailing Yacht 45m and above</li>
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Sailing Yacht of the Year</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – most innovative sailing yacht</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – best sailing yacht over 40m</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – best sailing yacht interior</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – highest technical achievement in a sailing yacht</li>
  <li>2007 International SuperYacht Society – best sailing yacht over 36m</li>
  <li>2009 Perini Navi Cup</li>
  <li>2010 Palma Superyacht Cup</li>
  <li>2011 Perini Navi Cup</li>
  <li>2012 Yacht Capital Marina Yachting</li>
  <li>2013 First Baccarat SuperYacht World trophy - Finest SuperYacht Ever</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `margin-left` and `margin-right` with fixed values (and units not supporting responsive design). So you can change your code like the following using `min-width` and `max-width`:

```css
.awards {
  background-color:grey;
  border:5px solid black;
  min-width:300px;
  max-width:400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<ul class = "awards">
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Best Sailing Yacht Interior</li>
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Best Sailing Yacht 45m and above</li>
  <li>2007 Boat International World SuperYacht Award – Sailing Yacht of the Year</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – most innovative sailing yacht</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – best sailing yacht over 40m</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – best sailing yacht interior</li>
  <li>2007 Showboats international Award – highest technical achievement in a sailing yacht</li>
  <li>2007 International SuperYacht Society – best sailing yacht over 36m</li>
  <li>2009 Perini Navi Cup</li>
  <li>2010 Palma Superyacht Cup</li>
  <li>2011 Perini Navi Cup</li>
  <li>2012 Yacht Capital Marina Yachting</li>
  <li>2013 First Baccarat SuperYacht World trophy - Finest SuperYacht Ever</li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** If you want to create a website which should be responsive for multiple devices you can use a CSS Framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look up and understand responsive design if you're concerned about websites adjusting to multiple screen sizes, that said, I think your approach has a lot of issues that make it not responsive.

If you're just trying to center the  element, the best way might be to set the left and right margins to auto:

```
.awards{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```